# Common Pages development in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I have one header that is common for my all pages in  my design for Phone Gap of  android development .Is there any way to do coding for it in one page and use it in all pages through call.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your mention of pages, are you using jQuery Mobile as a framework for your user interface? If so, you can use the pagebeforecreate event to copy a common header and/or footer to all of your pages. Something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforecreate', function(event, ui){
            $(this).prepend($('#scratch .common-header').clone());
            $(this).append($('#scratch .common-footer').clone());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
        <div data-role="content" style="min-height: 200px;">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
            <p>This is the first page.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page-2">
        <div data-role="content" style="min-height: 200px;">            
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
            <p>This is the second page.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="scratch" style="display: none;">
        <div class="common-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Common header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="common-footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page-1">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-2">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

'